# How to use Java streams for the filtering

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of object which has 3 variables(id, version, root_id)

`Eg : {(1, 3, 1001),(2,2,1001), (3,1,1001), (4,1,1002), (5,1,1003)}`

I want to retain only 1 object having same root_id and having highest version number.

`output : {(1, 3, 1001),(4,1,1002), (5,1,1003)}`

How can I apply the java stream filter on the list to get the desired output.
Please help. I am getting a bit confused on applying the filter.

Comment: Can't help without the definition of the object, which method it has, etc. And you haven't shown us your code and where you got confused.

Comment: Also, you did not specify the filter criteria. Which object should be returned if there are multiple objects with the same root id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `group` by `rootId` and take the `max` `version` by comparing `int` value.

`maxBy` returns `Optional` data, to unwrap the actaul data `collectingAndThen` is used

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Data> objects = Arrays.asList(new Data(1, 3, 1001), new Data(2, 2, 1001), new Data(3, 1, 1001),
            new Data(4, 1, 1002), new Data(5, 1, 1003));

    Map<Integer, Data> filtered = objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getRootId, Collectors
            .collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Data::getVersion)), Optional::get)));

    System.out.println(filtered.values());
}

static class Data {
    int id;
    int version;
    int rootId;

    //getter,setter & constructors
    //toString
}
```

output

```
[Data [id=1, version=3, rootId=1001], Data [id=4, version=1, rootId=1002], Data [id=5, version=1, rootId=1003]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How to do grouping on additional column from the same Data object. I mean I introduced variables extensionId and repositoryId. I want to group on these 3 columns. something like `objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::(getRootId,getExtensionId,getrepositoryId), Collectors
            .collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Data::getVersion)), Optional::get)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Class::property));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.stream().filter((item) -> {
     System.out.println(item); //this is element from your collection
     boolean isOk = true; //change true to your conditional
     return isOk;
})
```